# How to get a value of selected column by checkbox in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I get all the output from the row. Is it possible to get the value of selected "Points" only. How can I do this?

Expected output when checked:
SF01
SF02
SF03

Current output when checked:
    SF01
    11.5
    3.5328
    120.3359

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="selectTable" name="selectTable">
    <legend>Display Data Points</legend>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th width="40%">Point</th>
        <th width="20%">Depth</th>
        <th width="20%">Lat</th>
        <th width="20%">Long</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox[]" />
        </td>
        <td>SF01</td>
        <td>11.5</td>
        <td>3.5328</td>
        <td>120.3359</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox[]" />
        </td>
        <td>SF02</td>
        <td>41.5</td>
        <td>6.5328</td>
        <td>113.3359</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox[]" />
        </td>
        <td>SF03</td>
        <td>82.1</td>
        <td>5.2828</td>
        <td>721.9059</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickedBox() {

        var values = new Array();

        $.each($("input[name='checkBox[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"), function() {
            values.push($(this).text());

        });

        document.getElementById("boxArea").value = "=====Results=====\n" + values.join("\n");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectPoint").click(clickedBox);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Comparing the example of expected output with the HTML, it appears you mean you want to get the vlaues from a particular COLUMN, rather than Row? If that is so, please edit your question so that the meaning is apparent. Otherwise, you need to provide more clarification.

Comment: What element is `#selectPoint` here?

Comment: Add in `ready`, `$(':checkbox[name="checkBox[]"]').change(clickedBox);`

Comment: @Cindy yes, get value from column. My bad. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **[`siblings('td')`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to **[`next('td')`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** and I hope you need to bind `event` to `checkbox`.

```
$.each($("input[name='checkBox[]']:checked").closest("td").next("td"), function () {
                                                         //^^^^here
    values.push($(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ernkqbr2/)**

> When you say **[`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** then it will fetch all the `siblings` of first
>   `td`, which is why you are getting all the values.

Comment: Ahh! ok I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To keep it more simple-

Put your value using `data` attributes on element.

`<input type="checkbox" data-value="SF02"/>`

**jQuery-**

```
$(function(){
  values= new Array();
  $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),function(index,item){
    values.push(item.data('value');
  });
});
```